# How to retrieve specific text from a tag without using contains() and xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
<div>
    <label1>Hulk</label1>
    <label2>Ironman</label2>
Thor
</div>
```

How do I get only Thor text without using contains in xpath ?

If I try getting text of div it would give me all the 3 (Hulk, Ironman, Thor) but I want only Thor.

Comment: Show how did you try, current and desired output, add tag for your programming language

Comment: Assuming that the typo `<label1?` is fixed, and that there are no other `div`s in the document, `//div/text()` will select `Thor`.

Comment: @jsheeran , not in Selenium

Comment: @Andersson Can you help me out dude?

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_

Comment: @DebanjanB This was the only snippet they’ve asked me in technical interview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the text **Thor** without using contains in xpath you can use either of the following solutions:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  String myText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[not(@label)]")).getText();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  String myText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:not(label)")).getText();
  ```
- Using `JavaScriptExecutor`

  ```
  WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@attribute='value']")); //replace the pseudo attribute with actual attribute
  String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', myElement).toString();
  ```

**Note**: Ensure that *xpath* as `//div[not(@label)]` and *cssSelector* as `div:not(label)` resembles to a unique element on the HTML DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below mentioned path ?

```
/div/text()
```