# How to locate or extract texts in html file using selenium in python?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to locate or extract texts in a HTML file using Selenium in python. The text that I'm trying to get isn't an element.

```
<div class="datagrid row"> ==$0
 <h2 class="bottom-border block">Accepted Shipment</h2>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="hidden" id="looseAcceptedPieces" value="56"> == $0
      " 56 pcs."

    <!--Modified by A-7558 for ICRD-244765 starts--> == $0
    <input type="hidden" id="acceptedWt" value> == $0
     "952 kg"
```

How do i locate or get that text under `<input>`, which is **56 pcs.** and **952 kg**
perhaps, they are not elements.

Comment: You can read or take the entire html file as text file and then string search by "56 pcs"  if "56 pcs" appears only under <input> tag.

Comment: How about collecting text under td?, It will give  you 56 pcs., 952 kg in one string may be space-separated and than you can split it.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the values by using `get_attribute("value")` method

```
piece = driver.find_element_by_id('looseAcceptedPieces')
val = piece.get_attribute("value")
```

And

```
weight = driver.find_element_by_id('acceptedWt')
val2 = weight.get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the texts **56 pcs.** and **952 kg** as those are *text nodes* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` using `execute_script()` method and you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- To extract **56 pcs.**:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Accepted Shipment']//following::table[1]/tbody/tr/td")))).strip())
  ```
- To extract **952 kg**:

  ```
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;', WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Accepted Shipment']//following::table[1]/tbody/tr/td")))).strip())
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevent discussion in:

- [How to retrieve specific text from a tag without using contains() and xpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133912/how-to-retrieve-specific-text-from-a-tag-without-using-contains-and-xpath/51134989#51134989)
- [How to get text outside the div with selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60288910/how-to-get-text-outside-the-div-with-selenium/60289318#60289318)